# Retrofit - response.body.get... es nulo

Tags: java, android, retrofit, null, response

Estoy tratando de hacer un POST a una api, donde la respuesta de eso me da un TOKEN y otros datos

Perdon que les pegue mucho codigo pero es para que se entienda bien como lo tengo distribuido

```js
{
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8yMDYuMTg5LjE2OC4xOTA6ODA5MFwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1NzE4NTk1MDUsImV4cCI6MTU3MTg2MzEwNSwibmJmIjoxNTcxODU5NTA1LCJqdGkiOiJQZjNKcHdiWGplb3VKSHZTIiwic3ViIjoiODE2ODVhMzktMzA0OC00Yjk1LTg4ZjEtMGNmNTcwYTRlNTdlIiwicHJ2IjoiNTQwN2IwMTc5NzRlOTM2ZTFmNTM5NTVjMGQxMGIyNWM3YzA0M2UzYyJ9.PVt45a5VPYTUEv6v98E1lwl9fTZbjXqHHa47hC1nfrc",
        "user": {
            "uuid": "81685a39-3048-4b95-88f1-0cf570a4e57e",
            "name": "Admin",
            "surname": "Admin",
            "email": "admin@admin.com",
            "picture": "c217c9ca9c0d7477cbe851972492b055.jpeg",
            "birthdate": "1990-01-01",
            "phone": "112345678",
            "cel": "321123321",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "created_at": "2019-10-20 01:41:36",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-20 01:41:36"
        },
        "expiration_date": 1571863105000
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

mi ApiService es este:

```css
public interface LoginApiService {
    @POST("a/auth/login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

mi LoginResponse es este:

```css
  @SerializedName("token")
  @Expose
    private final String token;

    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private User user;

    @SerializedName("expiration_date")
    @Expose
    private long expirationDate;

    public LoginResponse(String token) {
        this.token = token;

    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public long getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate;
    }
```

Mi modulo de User es este:

```css
@SerializedName("uuid") @Expose private String uuid;
    @SerializedName("name") @Expose private String name;
    @SerializedName("surname") @Expose private String surname;
    @SerializedName("email") @Expose private String email;
    @SerializedName("picture") @Expose private String picture;
    @SerializedName("birthdate") @Expose private String birthdate;
    @SerializedName("phone") @Expose private String phone;
    @SerializedName("cel") @Expose private String cel;
    @SerializedName("email_verified_at") @Expose private String emailVerified;
    @SerializedName("created_at") @Expose private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at") @Expose private String updated_at;
    
    
    --constructor--
    --getter/setter--
```

Mi Retrofit Module:

```css
 private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

y mi ApiUtils

```css
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://206.189.168.190:8090/";

    public static LoginApiService getLoginApiService() {

        return RetrofitModule.getClient(BASE_URL).create(LoginApiService.class);
    }
```

Y cuando hago la llamada, entra en el onResponse, no me genera ningun tipo de fallo ni nada pero los metodos de LoginResponse son nulos

```css
LoginApiService loginApiService = ApiUtils.getLoginApiService();
        loginApiService.login("admin@admin.com", "123456").enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                Log.d("onResponse ", response.body().getToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Me tira este error cuando llega a ese Log.d(response.body.getToken)

```css
Process: com.example.socialsport, PID: 8871
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:145)
        at com.socialsportapp.socialsport.presentation.login.presenter.LoginPresenter$1.onResponse(LoginPresenter.java:45)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Estuve **Horas** buscando una solucion y no puedo entender. Yo supongo que es mi LoginResponse el cual hice algo mal pero no logro descubrir. Si pueden darse cuenta les agradeceria un monton. Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo Pablo, la respuesta viene encapsula en un node JSON parent `data{}` me animo a decir que tu `LoginResponse` debería tener un modelo `Data` y este mismo debería de tener los demás campos: "token, user, etc".

@SerializedName("data")
private final Data data;

Comment: Muchas gracias John. Por lo que veo tenes razon, se me paso por alto el data{}. Probare eso pero estoy seguro que es la respuesta.